# Why aren't comment up-votes converted to "stars" when the comment gets transferred over to chat?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat, chat-stars

Recently, a person commented on my answer to a [Literature question](http://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2444/why-is-the-turing-test-really-a-test-about-gender/2447#2447)...

> aroth: "...at least, according to Wikipedia" - Famous last words.

...and received at least 2 upvotes (possibly even 3). However, that comment then get moved over to [a chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58031/discussion-on-answer-by-tariq-ali-why-is-the-turing-test-really-a-test-about-gen), and aroth's current comment has 0 stars. That doesn't make much sense.  When it was just a normal comment, aroth had received upvotes and stars in Chat seems very similar to upvotes for comments. There's probably a really good reason for this process, so I'm wondering why this process exists.

Comment: Why should they be converted in such a manner?